# VBA filtering data between specific date format dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for help in filtering and selecting rows which falls between date format dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss. Below is my code which I am using. Have tried some other options too which were suggested in Stackoverflow but nothing worked.

Basically, my requirement is selecting mentioned date format from cell and applying it on a timestamp column. Creating a pivot table. Below is sample column data

[image]

```
Dim NmPivTbl As String, TimeStart As String, TimeEnd As String, CCY1 As String, ccy2 As String
Set Params = Range("A3")
TimeStart = Params.Offset(2, 2) #values picked from cell in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
TimeEnd = Params.Offset(3, 2)  #values picked from cell in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NmPivTbl).PivotFields("TimestampGMT").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(NmPivTbl).PivotFields("TimestampGMT").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=TimeStart, Value2:=TimeE nd
```

Comment: You will want to store date values in a date variable, not a string variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but I tried that too, but dint work.